# Curl A with no phi-dependence

Tags: vector-spaces, curl

So I know from wikipedia curl A is given by this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnxCL.png)

Then, how would this change if there were no phi-dependence, that is if A was only composed of p and z?

Thanks in adavnace.

Comment: Are you saying if $A = (A_{\rho}, A_{z}, 0)$?

Comment: @Unknown Yes. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In that case, all you can do is set the $A_{\varphi}$ to zero in you definition. You can still have $\varphi$ dependence on $A_{\rho}$ and $A_z$ so the derivatives with respect to $\varphi$ will not change, unless you know these components are also independent of $\varphi$.